# Fixed header on iOS scrolling slightly

Tags: css

I have a sub-header on one of the web pages I'm currently building. The position of this element is inherit, until it hits the top of the viewport, then I'm adding a `fixedPos` class via JavaScript.

```
.fixedPos{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
}
```

This class is being added. The issue is, when I scroll up and down the page the fixed header moves slightly with the content. I've done some research. Added these elements to the body tag to avoid this bug from continuing.

```
body{
    background-color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto; 
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

I have a viewport meta tag as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Issue is still occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/ej83w0k9/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= 100) {
    $(".fixed-header").addClass("fixedPos");
}
else{

 $(".fixed-header").removeClass("fixedPos");
}
});
```

And then your CSS:

```
.fixed-header {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
}

/*the fixed snippet, triggered by js*/
.fixedPos{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
  }

.fixed-header__nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: My sub-header does this. It just scrolls slightly on an iphone.